# javamail 535 authentication error

Tags: java, spring, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am using the following settings inside of Spring to create my mail sender.

```
  <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
      <property name="host" value="mail.heavyweight.com"/>
      <property name="password" value="xxxxxx"/>
      <property name="port" value="26"/>
      <property name="username" value="thom@heavyweight.com"/>
      <property name="session">
        <bean class="javax.mail.Session" factory-method="getDefaultInstance">
          <constructor-arg>
            <props>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.from">thom@heavyweight.com</prop>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.user">thom@heavyweight.com</prop>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
            </props>
          </constructor-arg>
          <property name="debug" value="true"/>
        </bean>
      </property>
  </bean>
```

Using the same SMTP server, user, and password that I use in my mail client.

When I try to send an email, I get this in the debug:

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true

DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.heavyweight.com", port 26, isSSL false
220-dyn.dynamicwebs.com ESMTP Exim 4.69 #1 Thu, 23 Feb 2012 16:55:27 -0600 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "mail.heavyweight.com", port: 26

EHLO motion
250-dyn.dynamicwebs.com Hello 74-133-195-24.dhcp.insightbb.com [74.133.195.24]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "52428800"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: check mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
dGhvbUBoZWF2eXdlaWdodHNvZnR3YXJlLmNvbQ==
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
[redacted]
535 Incorrect authentication data
```

So why do I get the 535? Any ideas?

I have successfully done this several times before without issue. Something specific about this server.

The password appears to be encrypted. Since I need the password to be unencrypted, won't this be a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if you mail service expects your password to be encoded?  Base64 perhaps?

Comment: @jowierun Since my mail client is sending unencrypted passwords, I'm going to assume this is going to need the same thing. I think this answers your question.

Comment: I hope that isn't your real password... if it is it's only base64 encoded and trivial to decode, so change it now (and make it so :-) I edited the post to redact the password.

Comment: As to the 535, unless the server is lying it means exactly what the RFC says -- the server rejected your credentials.  I suggest you try watching a "working" session from your email client with Wireshark to see what's really being transmitted.

Comment: Thanks, but yeah, it's not my real password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured my Spring bean in this way (from this [post](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/)), without using the `session` property (allows to send an email through the GMail SMTP servers) :

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
       <props>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
              <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
           </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And it works like a charm.
You may try it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I quit and used my Gmail account. Something's up with the hosting of my other account. I'm going to find a new provider.